# System.Runtime.serialization.dll not found on visual studio 2010

Tags: serialization, runtime, system

I have a class type project on my solution, and it has a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization, but, I can't find this dll on my Visual Studio to reference on the project.

Windows is 7 ultimate and is up to date, and my visual studio is up to date too.

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 6):

First of all you can perform a research in your system with the "System.Runtime.Serialization" keywords.

In my case this dll is situated into the folder "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0"(Windows XP).

After that if you didn't find it yet, you can check into References folder in Visual Studio:
"Add Reference/.NET"